# Align rows in text file with command line

Tags: text, command-line

I have data in a text file where data rows are repeated after several columns and each new block shares the first column of row labels. I'd like to use the command line to get align the rows into a single table.

The data text file looks like:

```
Values      SampleA     SampleB     SampleC
Value1      1.00        2.00        3.00
Value2      3.00        2.00        1.00
Value3      2.00        1.00        3.00

Values      SampleD     SampleE     SampleF
Value1      1.00        2.00        3.00
Value2      3.00        2.00        1.00
Value3      2.00        1.00        3.00
```

And I'd like the resulting file to look like:

```
Values      SampleA     SampleB     SampleC     SampleD     SampleE     SampleF
Value1      1.00        2.00        3.00        1.00        2.00        3.00
Value2      3.00        2.00        1.00        3.00        2.00        1.00
Value3      2.00        1.00        3.00        2.00        1.00        3.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution creates lots of temp files, but cleans up after.

```sh
# put each paragraph into it's own file:
awk -v RS= '{print > sprintf("%s_%06d", FILENAME, NR)}' data.txt 

# now, join them, and align the columns 
join data.txt_* | column -t | tee data.txt.joined

# and cleanup the temp files
rm data.txt_*
```

Verify afterwards with: `wc -l data.txt data.txt.joined`

Comment: It works if I change the 2nd command to:  `join -e data.txt_* | column -t | tee data.txt.joined`